# how to check special permissions in facebook

Tags: javascript, api, facebook, fbjs

how can i check in javascript 
 if user has granted my site the  publish stream permission

?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had this same problem but couldn't find any sample code. Anyways, I came up with this, which works for me. Hope this helps someone.

```
FB.api('/me/permissions', function (response) {
            var perms = response.data[0];

            if (perms.publish_stream) {                
                // User has permission
            } else {                
                // User DOESN'T have permission
            }                                            
    } );
```

Answer (score 7):

The API method you're looking for is **[Users.hasAppPermission](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/users.hasAppPermission)**. You could call it directly from JavaScript, but it will probably be more efficient to write your own HTTP method, that calls it via API and returns "true" or "false" via JSON.

There is also a **[filed bug (13378)](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=13378)** that [Users.hasAppPermission](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/users.hasAppPermission) has no Graph API equivalent.

Comment: It's in the Graph API now: https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions - http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

Answer (score 5):

In the new Graph API (including via JavaScript) this can be accomplished by accessing "`/[user]/permissions`".

From the [User object documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/):

`permissions`

> The permissions that user has granted the application.

> `array` containing a single object which has the keys as the permission
>   names and the values as the permission values (1/0) - Permissions with
>   value 0 are omitted from the object by default; also includes a `type`
>   field which is always `permissions`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like is not supported. At least is not [documented](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Using_the_Open_Stream_API#Prompting_for_Permission_to_Access_Streams).

You may read from javascript once the permission is granted though.