# Facebook: Is there a way to check that I have certain permissions?

Tags: facebook

I started developing a Facebook app using the new Graph API.

I want to check if I have certain permissions, (say `publish_stream` for example) for a certain user. I know that the old REST API had [`users.hasAppPermission`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/users.hasAppPermission), but I don't see anything parallel to that in the new Graph API.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to run FQL on [`permissions`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/permissions) table. If you are using JS SDK you can run it with [`FB.Data.query()`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Data.query).

Comment: Does this mean there is currently no way to accomplish this server-side using Graph API?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. In the new Graph API use `"/[user]/permissions"`. See also detailed explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563223/how-to-check-special-permissions-in-facebook) and [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/).