# Is it possible to get the status of extended permissions for a Facebook app with the Graph or REST API?

Tags: facebook, permissions

I want to check the status of the extended permissions for a user of my Facebook app. I don't want to request permissions, I just want to know what permissions they have already granted access to. Is this possible?

I'm happy to use the Graph or REST API to do this in PHP or JS.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219099/facebook-is-there-a-way-to-check-that-i-have-certain-permissions/3219976#3219976

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the JS SDK you can perform an [FQL query](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Data.query) to get any [extended permission](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/permissions):

```
FB.Data.query('select publish_stream, email from permissions where uid={0}', uid)
.wait(function(rows) {
  var permissions = [];
  if (rows.publish_stream) permissions.push("publish to stream");
  if (rows.email) permissions.push("send email");
  alert("Can "+permissions.join(", ");
});
```